# Type deduction for variable declared in lambda's capture

Tags: c++, lambda, capture, type-deduction

In this snippet I am declaring a variable `i` inside the lambda's capture.

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> vec;

    // Pushing 0-99 numbers to vector
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(vec), 100, [i = 0]() mutable { return i++; });

    return 0;
}
```

As one can see, there is no type stated anywhere for `i`.

As far as I know, I can write the equivalent functionality in this way:

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> vec;

    // Pushing 0-99 numbers to vector
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(vec), 100, [](){
             static int i = 0; 
             return i++; });

    return 0;
}
```

**How does the compiler know the type of `i` in the first example?** Is it deduced from the operation I perform on it (++) ? Does it know that it is `int` because of the container?

There are no complaints when compiling with GCC with -std=c++14 and -std=c++17.
Nevertheless, if I compile with -std=c++11 I get the following warning:

```
lambda_test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
lambda_test.cpp:24:51: warning: lambda capture initializers only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
  std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(first), 100, [i = 0]() mutable { return i++; });
                                                   ^
```

**MORE**: Given the comments, I tried to see a difference on what the compiler produces for c++11 and 14, but it generates the same code:
https://cppinsights.io/s/43411e6f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, you must activate C++14 for lambda capture initializer to work since it was added in C++14.

> As far as I know, I can write the equivalent functionality in this way:

No, static storage is functionally different. With capture you can copy the lambda and it will copy the state of the captures. With static variables each lambda access the same global.

> **How does the compiler know the type of i in the first example?** Is it deduced from the operation I perform on it (++) ? Does it know that it is int because of the container?

No, since many many types has the ++ operator.

The compiler simply use the initializer to deduce the type. You can see it as if there was a hidden `auto` there:

```
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(vec), 100, [/* auto */ i = 0]() mutable { return i++; });
```

The literal `0` is of type `int`. So `i` is an `int`.

You could technically do this too:

```
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(vec), 100, [/* auto */ i = 0ull]() mutable { return i++; });
```

Then `i` has the type `unsigned long long`, since the literal `0ull` is of that type.

Comment: If it was added in c++14, why does it compile anyway for -std=c++11 ? It also runs fine.

Comment: @daniglezad maybe your compiler accept it as an extension for c++11 and warn instead of reporting an error. It was quite common in the C++03 era to enable C++0x features as an extension

Answer (score 1):

It works just like it does when you do

```
auto i = 0;
```

You have to specify an initializer if you are not capturing an existing variable and that initializer is what is used to determine the type.